# Trying to replace my vanity light

Tags: lighting, vanity

I removed the old vanity light & found 2 sets of wires were connected to it. I'm confused what the red wire does. Switched breaker off & found it turns off the bathroom lights & my kitchen appliances. Ceiling & vanity lights have separate switches. I believe the red wire was capped off by itself & only twisted up with the black wires which were capped together.

Comment: are you saying that you do not know if the red eire was connected to anything when you started?

Answer (score 3):

When you are doing a direct replacement (e.g., light fixture for light fixture, even if the new one is fancy, new and LED instead of old and incandescent) you normally only have to be concerned with three wires:

- Switched Hot (typically black or red, but definitely not white or green or bare)
- Neutral (almost always white)
- Ground (green or bare)

You may or may not have a ground - some fixtures don't have one, metal boxes don't necessarily need one, etc. - ask if you are not sure what to do.

A single circuit can easily handle many light fixtures (especially with LEDs, but even with incandescent) and often many receptacles as well. A circuit controlling kitchen appliances should not, generally speaking, control anything outside the kitchen, but that may not have been a requirement when your house was built.

Often a switched circuit will be wired so that it could handle separately  switched light and fan, which would explain the capped red wire. *Just leave that wire capped as-is.*

Often there will be extra wires passing through a box. That's OK. *Leave them as-is*.

Just connect the same wires that were connected to the old light fixture to the new light fixture. Ignore the rest - unless it is falling apart or damaged.